# ElasticSearch Freezes and Crashes

Tags: elasticsearch

I have setup a cluster with 3 elasticsearch instances and they are being feed with documents provided by logstash (~165K docs per minute). I have those 3 machines with 16Gb RAM and each instance is started up with 8Gb.

The indexing works quite well, and I'm able to perform all required search operations I was expecting. The thing now is that I want to make it general available, but unfortunately depending on the queries that are executed (i.e. range facets over all indexes) it freezes the entire cluster and ends up in a split-brain state.

I already limited some things like:

```
indices.memory.index_buffer_size: 30%
indices.memory.min_shard_index_buffer_size: 12mb
indices.memory.min_index_buffer_size: 96mb

indices.fielddata.cache.size: 15%
indices.fielddata.cache.expire: 6h
indices.cache.filter.size: 15%
indices.cache.filter.expire: 6h
```

My entire config file looks like:

```
index.number_of_shards: 10
index.number_of_replicas: 0

bootstrap.mlockall: true

# Indices settings
indices.memory.index_buffer_size: 30%
indices.memory.min_shard_index_buffer_size: 12mb
indices.memory.min_index_buffer_size: 96mb

# Cache Sizes
indices.fielddata.cache.size: 15%
indices.fielddata.cache.expire: 6h
indices.cache.filter.size: 15%
indices.cache.filter.expire: 6h

# Indexing Settings for Writes
index.refresh_interval: 30s
index.translog.flush_threshold_ops: 50000
```

Is there something else I could improve here to avoid such freeze and split brain state?

**Output of my nodes info:**

```
{
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "nodes" : {
    "7i5sZj_jT_qe6HNESfzO3A" : {
      "name" : "Captain Fate",
      "transport_address" : "inet[/192.168.0.83:9300]",
      "host" : "esserver02",
      "ip" : "192.168.0.83",
      "version" : "1.1.1",
      "build" : "f1585f0",
      "http_address" : "inet[/192.168.0.83:9200]",
      "settings" : {
        "index" : {
          "number_of_replicas" : "0",
          "translog" : {
            "flush_threshold_ops" : "50000"
          },
          "number_of_shards" : "40",
          "refresh_interval" : "30s"
        },
        "bootstrap" : {
          "mlockall" : "true"
        },
        "transport" : {
          "tcp" : {
            "port" : "9300"
          }
        },
        "http" : {
          "port" : "9200"
        },
        "name" : "Captain Fate",
        "path" : {
          "logs" : "/opt/as/es/logs",
          "home" : "/opt/as/es"
        },
        "cluster" : {
          "name" : "elasticsearch"
        },
        "indices" : {
          "memory" : {
            "index_buffer_size" : "50%",
            "min_shard_index_buffer_size" : "12mb",
            "min_index_buffer_size" : "96mb"
          }
        },
        "discovery" : {
          "zen" : {
            "minimum_master_nodes" : "1",
            "ping" : {
              "unicast" : {
                "hosts" : [ "esserver02", "esserver03", "esserver04" ]
              },
              "multicast" : {
                "enabled" : "false"
              },
              "timeout" : "30s"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "os" : {
        "refresh_interval" : 1000,
        "available_processors" : 16
      },
      "process" : {
        "refresh_interval" : 1000,
        "id" : 8482,
        "max_file_descriptors" : 128000,
        "mlockall" : false
      },
      "jvm" : {
        "pid" : 8482,
        "version" : "1.7.0_45",
        "vm_name" : "Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM",
        "vm_version" : "24.45-b08",
        "vm_vendor" : "Oracle Corporation",
        "start_time" : 1411976625093,
        "mem" : {
          "heap_init_in_bytes" : 2147483648,
          "heap_max_in_bytes" : 12771524608,
          "non_heap_init_in_bytes" : 24313856,
          "non_heap_max_in_bytes" : 136314880,
          "direct_max_in_bytes" : 12771524608
        },
        "gc_collectors" : [ "ParNew", "ConcurrentMarkSweep" ],
        "memory_pools" : [ "Code Cache", "Par Eden Space", "Par Survivor Space", "CMS Old Gen", "CMS Perm Gen" ]
      },
      "thread_pool" : {
        "generic" : {
          "type" : "cached",
          "keep_alive" : "30s"
        },
        "index" : {
          "type" : "fixed",
          "min" : 16,
          "max" : 16,
          "queue_size" : "200"
        },
        "get" : {
          "type" : "fixed",
          "min" : 16,
          "max" : 16,
          "queue_size" : "1k"
        },
        "snapshot" : {
          "type" : "scaling",
          "min" : 1,
          "max" : 5,
          "keep_alive" : "5m"
        },
        "merge" : {
          "type" : "scaling",
          "min" : 1,
          "max" : 5,
          "keep_alive" : "5m"
        },
        "suggest" : {
          "type" : "fixed",
          "min" : 16,
          "max" : 16,
          "queue_size" : "1k"
        },
        "bulk" : {
          "type" : "fixed",
          "min" : 16,
          "max" : 16,
          "queue_size" : "50"
        },
        "optimize" : {
          "type" : "fixed",
          "min" : 1,
          "max" : 1
        },
        "warmer" : {
          "type" : "scaling",
          "min" : 1,
          "max" : 5,
          "keep_alive" : "5m"
        },
        "flush" : {
          "type" : "scaling",
          "min" : 1,
          "max" : 5,
          "keep_alive" : "5m"
        },
        "search" : {
          "type" : "fixed",
          "min" : 48,
          "max" : 48,
          "queue_size" : "1k"
        },
        "percolate" : {
          "type" : "fixed",
          "min" : 16,
          "max" : 16,
          "queue_size" : "1k"
        },
        "management" : {
          "type" : "scaling",
          "min" : 1,
          "max" : 5,
          "keep_alive" : "5m"
        },
        "refresh" : {
          "type" : "scaling",
          "min" : 1,
          "max" : 8,
          "keep_alive" : "5m"
        }
      },
      "network" : {
        "refresh_interval" : 5000
      },
      "transport" : {
        "bound_address" : "inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9300]",
        "publish_address" : "inet[/192.168.0.83:9300]"
      },
      "http" : {
        "bound_address" : "inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9200]",
        "publish_address" : "inet[/192.168.0.83:9200]",
        "max_content_length_in_bytes" : 104857600
      },
      "plugins" : [ {
        "name" : "head",
        "version" : "NA",
        "description" : "No description found.",
        "url" : "/_plugin/head/",
        "jvm" : false,
        "site" : true
      } ]
    },
    "0OaMqY6IR1SYeL6rd6P61Q" : {
      "name" : "Blonde Phantom",
      "transport_address" : "inet[/192.168.0.100:9300]",
      "host" : "esserver03",
      "ip" : "192.168.0.100",
      "version" : "1.1.1",
      "build" : "f1585f0",
      "http_address" : "inet[/192.168.0.100:9200]",
      "settings" : {
        "index" : {
          "number_of_replicas" : "0",
          "translog" : {
            "flush_threshold_ops" : "50000"
          },
          "number_of_shards" : "40",
          "refresh_interval" : "30s"
        },
        "bootstrap" : {
          "mlockall" : "true"
        },
        "transport" : {
          "tcp" : {
            "port" : "9300"
          }
        },
        "http" : {
          "port" : "9200"
        },
        "name" : "Blonde Phantom",
        "path" : {
          "logs" : "/opt/as/es/logs",
          "home" : "/opt/as/es"
        },
        "cluster" : {
          "name" : "elasticsearch"
        },
        "indices" : {
          "memory" : {
            "index_buffer_size" : "50%",
            "min_shard_index_buffer_size" : "12mb",
            "min_index_buffer_size" : "96mb"
          }
        },
        "discovery" : {
          "zen" : {
            "minimum_master_nodes" : "1",
            "ping" : {
              "unicast" : {
                "hosts" : [ "esserver02", "esserver03", "esserver04" ]
              },
              "multicast" : {
                "enabled" : "false"
              },
              "timeout" : "30s"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "os" : {
        "refresh_interval" : 1000,
        "available_processors" : 16
      },
      "process" : {
        "refresh_interval" : 1000,
        "id" : 98772,
        "max_file_descriptors" : 128000,
        "mlockall" : false
      },
      "jvm" : {
        "pid" : 98772,
        "version" : "1.7.0_45",
        "vm_name" : "Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM",
        "vm_version" : "24.45-b08",
        "vm_vendor" : "Oracle Corporation",
        "start_time" : 1414657551806,
        "mem" : {
          "heap_init_in_bytes" : 2147483648,
          "heap_max_in_bytes" : 12771524608,
          "non_heap_init_in_bytes" : 24313856,
          "non_heap_max_in_bytes" : 136314880,
          "direct_max_in_bytes" : 12771524608
        },
        "gc_collectors" : [ "ParNew", "ConcurrentMarkSweep" ],
        "memory_pools" : [ "Code Cache", "Par Eden Space", "Par Survivor Space", "CMS Old Gen", "CMS Perm Gen" ]
      },
      "thread_pool" : {
        "generic" : {
          "type" : "cached",
          "keep_alive" : "30s"
        },
        "index" : {
          "type" : "fixed",
          "min" : 16,
          "max" : 16,
          "queue_size" : "200"
        },
        "get" : {
          "type" : "fixed",
          "min" : 16,
          "max" : 16,
          "queue_size" : "1k"
        },
        "snapshot" : {
          "type" : "scaling",
          "min" : 1,
          "max" : 5,
          "keep_alive" : "5m"
        },
        "merge" : {
          "type" : "scaling",
          "min" : 1,
          "max" : 5,
          "keep_alive" : "5m"
        },
        "suggest" : {
          "type" : "fixed",
          "min" : 16,
          "max" : 16,
          "queue_size" : "1k"
        },
        "bulk" : {
          "type" : "fixed",
          "min" : 16,
          "max" : 16,
          "queue_size" : "50"
        },
        "optimize" : {
          "type" : "fixed",
          "min" : 1,
          "max" : 1
        },
        "warmer" : {
          "type" : "scaling",
          "min" : 1,
          "max" : 5,
          "keep_alive" : "5m"
        },
        "flush" : {
          "type" : "scaling",
          "min" : 1,
          "max" : 5,
          "keep_alive" : "5m"
        },
        "search" : {
          "type" : "fixed",
          "min" : 48,
          "max" : 48,
          "queue_size" : "1k"
        },
        "percolate" : {
          "type" : "fixed",
          "min" : 16,
          "max" : 16,
          "queue_size" : "1k"
        },
        "management" : {
          "type" : "scaling",
          "min" : 1,
          "max" : 5,
          "keep_alive" : "5m"
        },
        "refresh" : {
          "type" : "scaling",
          "min" : 1,
          "max" : 8,
          "keep_alive" : "5m"
        }
      },
      "network" : {
        "refresh_interval" : 5000,
        "primary_interface" : {
          "address" : "",
          "name" : "",
          "mac_address" : ""
        }
      },
      "transport" : {
        "bound_address" : "inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0%0:9300]",
        "publish_address" : "inet[/192.168.0.100:9300]"
      },
      "http" : {
        "bound_address" : "inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0%0:9200]",
        "publish_address" : "inet[/192.168.0.100:9200]",
        "max_content_length_in_bytes" : 104857600
      },
      "plugins" : [ {
        "name" : "head",
        "version" : "NA",
        "description" : "No description found.",
        "url" : "/_plugin/head/",
        "jvm" : false,
        "site" : true
      } ]
    },
    "H2h01oNGSuCL0uu8J3SF6w" : {
      "name" : "Dakimh the Enchanter",
      "transport_address" : "inet[/192.168.0.101:9300]",
      "host" : "esserver04",
      "ip" : "192.168.0.101",
      "version" : "1.1.1",
      "build" : "f1585f0",
      "http_address" : "inet[/192.168.0.101:9200]",
      "settings" : {
        "index" : {
          "number_of_replicas" : "0",
          "translog" : {
            "flush_threshold_ops" : "50000"
          },
          "number_of_shards" : "40",
          "refresh_interval" : "30s"
        },
        "bootstrap" : {
          "mlockall" : "true"
        },
        "transport" : {
          "tcp" : {
            "port" : "9300"
          }
        },
        "http" : {
          "port" : "9200"
        },
        "name" : "Dakimh the Enchanter",
        "path" : {
          "logs" : "/opt/as/es/logs",
          "home" : "/opt/as/es"
        },
        "cluster" : {
          "name" : "elasticsearch"
        },
        "indices" : {
          "memory" : {
            "index_buffer_size" : "50%",
            "min_shard_index_buffer_size" : "12mb",
            "min_index_buffer_size" : "96mb"
          }
        },
        "discovery" : {
          "zen" : {
            "minimum_master_nodes" : "1",
            "ping" : {
              "unicast" : {
                "hosts" : [ "esserver02", "esserver03", "esserver04" ]
              },
              "multicast" : {
                "enabled" : "false"
              },
              "timeout" : "30s"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "os" : {
        "refresh_interval" : 1000,
        "available_processors" : 16
      },
      "process" : {
        "refresh_interval" : 1000,
        "id" : 88019,
        "max_file_descriptors" : 128000,
        "mlockall" : false
      },
      "jvm" : {
        "pid" : 88019,
        "version" : "1.7.0_45",
        "vm_name" : "Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM",
        "vm_version" : "24.45-b08",
        "vm_vendor" : "Oracle Corporation",
        "start_time" : 1414657560829,
        "mem" : {
          "heap_init_in_bytes" : 2147483648,
          "heap_max_in_bytes" : 12771524608,
          "non_heap_init_in_bytes" : 24313856,
          "non_heap_max_in_bytes" : 136314880,
          "direct_max_in_bytes" : 12771524608
        },
        "gc_collectors" : [ "ParNew", "ConcurrentMarkSweep" ],
        "memory_pools" : [ "Code Cache", "Par Eden Space", "Par Survivor Space", "CMS Old Gen", "CMS Perm Gen" ]
      },
      "thread_pool" : {
        "generic" : {
          "type" : "cached",
          "keep_alive" : "30s"
        },
        "index" : {
          "type" : "fixed",
          "min" : 16,
          "max" : 16,
          "queue_size" : "200"
        },
        "get" : {
          "type" : "fixed",
          "min" : 16,
          "max" : 16,
          "queue_size" : "1k"
        },
        "snapshot" : {
          "type" : "scaling",
          "min" : 1,
          "max" : 5,
          "keep_alive" : "5m"
        },
        "merge" : {
          "type" : "scaling",
          "min" : 1,
          "max" : 5,
          "keep_alive" : "5m"
        },
        "suggest" : {
          "type" : "fixed",
          "min" : 16,
          "max" : 16,
          "queue_size" : "1k"
        },
        "bulk" : {
          "type" : "fixed",
          "min" : 16,
          "max" : 16,
          "queue_size" : "50"
        },
        "optimize" : {
          "type" : "fixed",
          "min" : 1,
          "max" : 1
        },
        "warmer" : {
          "type" : "scaling",
          "min" : 1,
          "max" : 5,
          "keep_alive" : "5m"
        },
        "flush" : {
          "type" : "scaling",
          "min" : 1,
          "max" : 5,
          "keep_alive" : "5m"
        },
        "search" : {
          "type" : "fixed",
          "min" : 48,
          "max" : 48,
          "queue_size" : "1k"
        },
        "percolate" : {
          "type" : "fixed",
          "min" : 16,
          "max" : 16,
          "queue_size" : "1k"
        },
        "management" : {
          "type" : "scaling",
          "min" : 1,
          "max" : 5,
          "keep_alive" : "5m"
        },
        "refresh" : {
          "type" : "scaling",
          "min" : 1,
          "max" : 8,
          "keep_alive" : "5m"
        }
      },
      "network" : {
        "refresh_interval" : 5000,
        "primary_interface" : {
          "address" : "",
          "name" : "",
          "mac_address" : ""
        }
      },
      "transport" : {
        "bound_address" : "inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0%0:9300]",
        "publish_address" : "inet[/192.168.0.101:9300]"
      },
      "http" : {
        "bound_address" : "inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0%0:9200]",
        "publish_address" : "inet[/192.168.0.101:9200]",
        "max_content_length_in_bytes" : 104857600
      },
      "plugins" : [ {
        "name" : "head",
        "version" : "NA",
        "description" : "No description found.",
        "url" : "/_plugin/head/",
        "jvm" : false,
        "site" : true
      } ]
    }
  }
}
```

My old configuration:

```
index.number_of_shards: 40
index.number_of_replicas: 0

bootstrap.mlockall: true

## Threadpool Settings ##

# Indices settings
indices.memory.index_buffer_size: 50%
indices.memory.min_shard_index_buffer_size: 12mb
indices.memory.min_index_buffer_size: 96mb

# Indexing Settings for Writes
index.refresh_interval: 30s
index.translog.flush_threshold_ops: 50000
```

Comment: just attached, that is the result of the cluster with the old configuration

Comment: @Tom83: you are right, I already applied the configuration

Comment: @Tom83: could you see other improvements possible with the configuration and result of node stats?

Comment: I sum up my comments in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your `indices.fielddata.cache.size` is set to 15% only. Why?

These data are used for aggregations/facets so it could be related. You should remove `indices.fielddata.cache.expire` ASAP : this setting is really not recommended at all, as evictions are really costful and it schedules evictions for fielddata values, **even if they are used**. Could you give us the result of a node stats API ?

Update 1 :

I see `minimum_master_nodes` is set to 1, but you say you have 3 nodes. This should be set to 2 according to the equation generally used (number of nodes/2 + 1, [documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_important_configuration_changes.html#_minimum_master_nodes))

Update 2 :

Do you still experience split-brains with the updated configuration?

Depending on your cluster ES version (> 1.0) , you might want to tune the fielddata circuit-breaker to prevent the most costly requests to be done : take a look [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-fielddata.html#fielddata-circuit-breaker).

Comment: what would be a good value for the indices.fielddata.cache.size? 30%?

Comment: I invite you to read this [section](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_limiting_memory_usage.html#fielddata-size) of the definitive guide. This setting is only a limit, that will trigger fielddata evictions when their size reach it. You can try with 30%, let your cluster live, and monitor the `fielddata.evictions` attribute from a `GET _nodes/stats/indices` response to fine-tune it.